# Is there a way to get the table data is fetched from?

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to get the current table data is fetched from?

Maybe easier to give an example:

```
Select 
       current server       -> Returns "PDBS" or whatever
     , current table(a)     -> Is there something similar that would return "customer"?
     , a.customer_no
     , b.order_no
  from customer a
  left join orders b
    on b.customer_no     = a.customer_no
 where 
       customer_no       = 123456
     ;
```

Edit:
The reason I'm asking is that we have a number of tables (20ish) with descriptions for different things with language support. We have 3 test environments and production and I've written a script that identifies discrepancies in the environments.
I have hardcoded the table names and in doing so was curious if there was a way to extract the table names directly...

Comment: Use case unclear - if you code FROM customer you could also do a SELECT 'customer' as table, ...

Comment: @bek No. There is no such an ability in Db2.

Comment: Does the function or register described in the question exist in any SQL DBMS?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher legitimate question :)
The reason I'm asking is that we have a number of tables (20ish) with descriptions for different things with language support. We have 3 test environments and production and I've written a script that identifies discrepancies in the environments.
I have hardcoded the table names and in doing so was curious if there was a way to extract the table name directly...